# JQuery nested $.when ... then statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a FreeCodeCamp exercise where I call the Twitch TV API. For each channel I make a call to the API to get the channel data. I then make a subsequent call to get the streaming data. The call for the channel information is wrapped in a  $.when ... then loop and seems to work fine. I then added a second call to get the stream data and code does not seem to wait for that call to complete.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  'use strict';

  var dataArray = []; // This holds all the channels that I find. I then sort to get the most popular first.

  $.when(
    // TODO this should be some sort of loop to make it more flexible
    getChannelData("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/channels?api_version=3&q=all&limit=10&offset=0&callback=?") // First 10
  ).then(function() {
    sortData();
    displayData();
  });

  function getChannelData(channelStatement) {

    return $.getJSON(channelStatement, function(channelData) {

      channelData.channels.forEach(function(element) {

        // Get stream details
        var channel;

        channel = {
          logo: (element.logo === null) ? "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/White_square_with_question_mark.png" : element.logo, // Channel: Url for image
          displayName: element.display_name, // Channel: Broadcaster name
          channelName: element.name, // Channel: Channel name
          url: element.url, // Channel: Used to generate link to twitch page
          game: element.game, // Channel: As the name suggests
          status: element.status, // Chaneel: Description of the stream
          views: element.views, // Channel: As the name suggests
          onLine: true
        };

        //dataArray.push(channel);

        var streamUrl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + element.name + "?api_version=3&callback=?";

        $.when(
            getStreamData(streamUrl, channel)
          )
          .then(function() {
            dataArray.push(channel);
          });
      }); // channel data forEach
    });
  }


  function getStreamData(streamUrl, channel) {
    return $.getJSON(streamUrl, function(stream) {
      channel.onLine = (stream.stream === null) ? false : true;
    });
  }


  function sortData() {

  }

  function displayData() {

  }
}); // end ready
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>Twitch TV</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ol id="twitchList">
        </ol>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="TwitchTV.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hemovu/edit?js) link shows the code. Line 51 shows the second ajax call.

The code should populate an array and then on completion of all the calls display the data. I appreciate that with a production system waiting for all these calls to complete will lead to a less than idea user experience.

Comment: The code should be included in your question. JSBin link is not required, but couldn't hurt to be in the question, however the code is required in the question.

Comment: Updated with code as recommended.

Comment: It's certainly possible to do what you're asking, but it's a rather wasteful use of HTTP requests. Any chance you can restrict your stream data to be displayed only when the user requests to see some information from it, rather than immediately? You can imagine if you were returned 20 or so channels, you'd then have to make an additional 20 HTTP requests (and wait for them to finish) before you could display **anything**

Comment: The problem you are having is due to the fact that the promise you are returning from getChannelData is not also wrapping the new promise you are creating later with $.when in the callback.

Comment: @Adam. This is purely a training exercise and I agree that it is not sensible in a real environment ... however as a learning experience I am interested in making it work to increase my limited understanding of javascript\jquery development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-oganize it slightly so that the promise you return from getChannelData is waiting on the promises created within your forEach.

```
  function getChannelData(channelStatement) {

    return $.getJSON(channelStatement).then(function(channelData) {

      return $.when.apply(null, channelData.channels.map(function(element) {

        // Get stream details
        var channel = {
          logo: (element.logo === null) ? "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/White_square_with_question_mark.png" : element.logo, // Channel: Url for image
          displayName: element.display_name, // Channel: Broadcaster name
          channelName: element.name, // Channel: Channel name
          url: element.url, // Channel: Used to generate link to twitch page
          game: element.game, // Channel: As the name suggests
          status: element.status, // Chaneel: Description of the stream
          views: element.views, // Channel: As the name suggests
          onLine: true
        };

        //dataArray.push(channel);

        var streamUrl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + element.name + "?api_version=3&callback=?";

        return getStreamData(streamUrl, channel);
      }); // channel data map
    });
  }
```

you would then use it like:

```
getChannelData(whatever).then(function () {
  console.log(arguments); // this is dataArray
});
```

Comment: Worked a treat, the only change I made to your code was to add back in the commented out line that populates the array. I'm now going to stare at the code for the next hour to make sure I understand it! Thank you for your help.